# How to run MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have this error.

```
exception data directory C:\data\db not found
```

But I have in mongod.cfg:

```
# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\data\db
```

But it does not work for me, it says `not found directory`.
What I am doing wrong?

I tried to create in User directory: "mongobase" and set it. Still receving same error.

Comment: `c:\data\db` is the default location for the `mongod` data file. So either you have not used `--config` to point at MONGOD.CFG or that path is not valid and is being ignored.

Comment: yes, i created C:\data\db and it works, but still config desnt work

Comment: You may need to put that path in quotes as it as a space in it.